# Is there any API for implementing Mobile Device management system/MDM

Tags: ios, mdm

In MDM implementation, I need to send some link to the Handheld ios device on clicking to it, should automatically install software, or update it, provide remote wipe all the data from the phone’s internal memory and reset the device back to its factory default settings. we could remove apps that affect our employees’ productivity and drain our data plans. We could be able to click button on device remotely, share our screen.
How should we implement these kind of features using MDM?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server
You can remotely install apps,wipe data  through this MDM solution

Comment: After implementing this project U can understand the flow.